# Python: Use key of formatting string multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, keyerror

I have a formatting string:

```
test = 'I am a string and {key}'
```

Now I want to use the key of this string multiple times to change the string dynamically:

```
test = test.format(key="hello1")
print(test)
test = test.format(key="hello2")
print(test)
```

After this I get a `KeyError: "key"` because the key "key" is overwritten. How can I access the key multiple times without copying the string by `copy(test)` and without renaming the string? Is there another way to format a string and keep the key?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're after. You're re-declaring the variable in your loop, which is overwriting your template string with a formatted string. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense: after you've replaced `{key}` with whatever value (which is the entire point of `str.format`) it doesn't exist anymore. What do you intend / what are you attempting to do / what would you expect exactly?

Comment: I am so confused by this question. Formatting means replacing the {key} part of the string with whatever you specify. What do you mean by accessing the key mutliple times?

Comment: The error also doesn't match the snippet you've provided: `str.format` will replace placeholders by specified values. After the first placement there is no placeholder left, `str.format` just does nothing, it doesn't raise an error. Please don't provide code snippets unrelated to the question you're asking.

Comment: In the first iteration itself the test variable's key will be replaced by "hello" due to the below line:

    test = test.format(key="hello")
Hence, you are getting error on the second iteration as there is no "{key}" in the test variable

Comment: Using f strings may help for constructing strings based on index if that is what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I adapted my question. My goal is to use the variable like it is firstly declared multiple times. I just want to format the string multiple times like by the same key.

Comment: The premise is nonsense. Formatting the string multiple times, even if you could do it in this way, would gain you nothing: You still have the same string at the end of your logic. If you want to re-use a template string, you *must* not overwrite it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I adapted my question: The string should be changed

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The ultimate answer to your question is *no*. You cannot overwrite a variable with different data then re-use that variable as if you didn't change anything. To my knowledge, no language would allow syntax like this, as it's illogical.

When you declare a variable with `test =`, you are assigning `test` to a memory location. When you re-declare with `test.format`, you're assigning `test` to an entirely different memory location. Proof:

```py
test = 'I am a string and {key}'
print(id(test))

test = test.format(key="hello1")
print(id(test))

> 1550435806864
> 1550435807104
```

Could you theoretically store the original memory location and grab that? Maybe, if garbage collection hasn't already cleaned up that location. *Should* you? Absolutely not. I'd guess trying to do that would lead to a memory leak.

---

**Original Answer**

You're overwriting your template string with an entirely new string. Try this instead:

```py
template = 'I am a string and {key}'

test = template.format(key="hello")
print(test)
test = template.format(key="goodbye")
print(test)
```

Comment: The case is that I don't want to create a new variable. I want to use the template variable and changing the key multiple times

Comment: You can't. Python doesn't work this way. Can you explain *why* you want to do this? I can think of no legitimate reason, so a bit of context might help us solve the actual problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @SamMorgan said, if you want multiple outputs just use a while or a for loop instead of typing it repetitively.
for example, for a defined number of times, use for loop-

```py
    test='this is a {key}'
    for i in range(5):
        c=input()
        print(test.format(key=c))
```